# Search through an array and find biggest object

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C# and I have an assignment to create a program to sort through two arrays and find the biggest fish based on the user color input. I have no idea how to make it work. Can anybody give me some pointers? Here is what I have so far.

```
Console.WriteLine("Select a fish color. \nEnter only the number.\n1. 
Black\n2. Green\n3. Red\n4. Blue\n5. Yellow\nEnter Your Selection:");

string userColor = Console.ReadLine();
int value;
while (!(int.TryParse(userColor, out value) && value >=1 && value <=5))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please type only numbers from 1 to 5");
    userColor = Console.ReadLine();
}

int color = int.Parse(userColor);

string[] colors = new string[] { "Black", "Black", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Black", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Black", "Green", "Red", "Blue","Yellow"};

double[] lenght = new double[] { 8.5, 9.8, 10.9, 40, 36, 45, 43, 12, 17.8, 13.5, 14.9, 27.7, 26.9, 50, 60,13 };

Console.WriteLine("You chose " + colors[color]);
Console.WriteLine("The biggest " + colors[color] + " fish is " + lenght[color]+ " inches long.");
```

Comment: The solution is simple. I want you to tickle yours brain cells so that you will become part of wonderful stack overflow community. ZIP is one of the way in Linq read that

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to do two things:

1. Find each fish which match the color you are searching for.
2. Find the largest corresponding number within the fish of that color.

I'll try to give you a place to start, and one example of the tools you might use:

- You should probably use a `for` loop, since this will let you easily loop through values in both lists.
- Once you map the user input number to the color as a string, you can use `==` to compare fish colors.
- You can keep track of the biggest fish length found so far in its own variable and update it when needed.

(P.S. I am intentionally keeping things vague and newbie-friendly. If I were solving it for myself, I would probably try to find a way to solve this problem in 2-3 lines, but that would require more understanding than you have so far.)